# How to pass arguments with special characters to call shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, quoting

Calling .sh(shell script) with the required parameters as below :-

```
sh home/example.sh --context_param dbUserName=username --context_param dbPassword=exam!ple##### --context_param resultDate=2017-01-13
```

calling example.sh with paramters dbUsername and password but getting following error:-

> -bash: !ple#####: event not found

I think special characters restrict the command to execute. Then how i have to pass the special characters. Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 10):

Change the line,

```
dbPassword=exam!ple#####
```

to,

```
dbPassword='exam!ple#####'
```

to avoid `!` (history-expansion) being treated specially in `bash`

From `man bash` under `QUOTING` sub-section,

> When  the command history expansion facilities are being used (see HISTORY EXPANSION below), the history expansion character, usually !, must be quoted to prevent history expansion.

more under `HISTORY EXPANSION`

> History expansions are  introduced  by
>          the  appearance  of  the  history  expansion  character,  which is ! by
>          default.  Only backslash (`\`) and single quotes can  quote  the  history
>          expansion character.

Also, it is a good practice to quote all your `name-value` pairs to prevent Word-splitting done by shell.

```
sh home/example.sh --context_param dbUserName="username" --context_param dbPassword='exam!ple#####' --context_param resultDate="2017-01-13"
```

About word-splitting, from the `man` page,

> Word Splitting
>
> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that **did not occur within double quotes for word splitting**. The shell treats each character of `IFS` as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators

Comment: Inian thanks for sharing your valuable knowledge. like i already tried these cases, are you sure only this should be the solution because i got error after doing the same u suggest, now i think it could be be because of script is not correct. so just confirming you are you sure about the solution?

Comment: @RanjitSingh: Running it as `sh home/example.sh --context_param dbUserName="username" --context_param dbPassword='exam!ple#####' --context_param resultDate="2017-01-13"` should not throw any errors w.r.t quoting, but I cannot vouch for the rest of your script.

Comment: I was trying to run nextcloud occ command from command line, and was trying to pass the password as one of the parameters, when it was failing, as the password had special character. So this definitely worked for me. Make sure when quoting the value, use single quote, instead of double quote.

Answer (score 3):

Pass it like this:

```
exam\!ple\#\#\#\#\#
```

Test:

```
echo exam\!ple\#\#\#\#\#
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following two things:

1. **Escape every single special symbol with a backslash**

   ```
   sh home/example.sh --context_param dbUserName=username --context_param dbPassword=exam\!ple\#\#\#\#\# --context_param resultDate=2017-01-13
   ```
2. **Singlequote the entire argument**.

   ```
   sh home/example.sh --context_param dbUserName=username --context_param dbPassword='exam!ple#####' --context_param resultDate=2017-01-13
   ```

From `man bash`

> **QUOTING**
>
> Quoting is used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or words to the shell.  Quoting can be used to disable 
>   special  treatment for special characters, to prevent reserved words from being recognized as such, and to prevent parameter expansion.
>
> When  the  command  history  expansion facilities are being used, the history expansion character,usually `!`,must be quoted to prevent history expansion.
>
> There are three quoting mechanisms: the **escape character**, **single quotes**, and **double quotes**.
>
> A **non-quoted backslash (\)** is the escape character.  It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows, with the  exception
>   of `<newline>`.  If a `\<newline>` pair appears, and the backslash is not itself quoted, the `\<newline>` is treated as a line continuation
>   (that is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).
>
> **Enclosing characters in single quotes** preserves the literal value of each character within the  quotes.   A  single  quote  may not  occur
>   between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> **Enclosing  characters in double quotes** preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`,`,`\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`.  The characters `$` and ` retain their special meaning within double quotes. The backslash
>   retains its special  meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `, `"`, `\`, or `<newline>`.  A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash.  If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an `!`  appearing in  double 
>   quotes  is escaped using a backslash.  The backslash preceding the `!`  is not removed.
>
> The special parameters `*` and `@` have special meaning when in double quotes.
>
> Words  of the form `$'string'` are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.
>
> Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> ```
>           \a     alert (bell)
>           \b     backspace
>           \e
>           \E     an escape character
>           \f     form feed
>           \n     new line
>           \r     carriage return
>           \t     horizontal tab
>           \v     vertical tab
>           \\     backslash
>           \'     single quote
>           \"     double quote
>           \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)
>           \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>           \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
>           \UHHHHHHHH
>                  the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
>           \cx    a control-x character
> ```
>
> The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.
>
> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will cause the string to be translated according to the  current locale. If the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored.  If the string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.