# Mysql temp password consists of characters like '<'

Tags: mysql

So I am using ansible to install MySQL 5.7 on Centos 7. In MySQL 5.7 after mysql is installed , the temp root password is stored in /var/log/mysqld.log. What my ansible task does is it reads the temp password and then updates the root user's password to a custom one.
Everything was working fine while I was testing it, until this time when the random generated password `,:<vtBo6_q-h` .Due to the `<` in the password I am not able to login into Mysql and change the root password. Is there any way to limit the characters in the temp password while installing mysql? Or is there a way to escape these characters while logging into mysql using ansible?

Here is my Ansible Task:

```
- name: Update the mysql root password


mysql_user: name=root
          password="'{{ mysql_root_password }}'"
          check_implicit_admin=yes
          login_user=root
          login_password="{{ temp_password }}"
          state=present


ignore_errors: yes
```

I also tried to manually login using terminal

```
mysql -uroot -p,:<vtBo6_q-h
bash: vtBo6_q-h: No such file or directory
```

So the solution seems to put the password in quotes. This is working on the terminal but passing the password with single quotes in ansible does not seem to work

Comment: how are you trying to login? please show us the command

Comment: Have you tried contacting Ansible? They seem to be a commercial party.

Comment: have you tried `mysql -u USERNAME -p',:<vtBo6_q-h'`

Comment: @PhilippSander Added the tasks

Comment: @PhilippSander The quotes worked on the terminal , but when using it on ansible, its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments with special characters to call shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106102/how-to-pass-arguments-with-special-characters-to-call-shell-script)

Comment: @Quentin That solution works on the shell prompt but not as an Ansible task

Comment: so why not login via shell and change the password?

Comment: @PhilippSander Can't do that. This task is part of a huge Ansible Playbook and everything is automated.

Comment: How about a `shell:` task?